# A contradiction in the Set Theory of von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, independence-results

Thinking on the theory NBG (of von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel) I arrived at the conclusion that it is contradictory using an argument resembling Russell's Paradox. I am sure that I made a mistake in my arguments (because NBG cannot be contradictory, as all mathematicians believe), but I can not find the exact place where the error happened.

The [theory NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) is finitely axiomatizable theory whose undefined notions are "class" and "element". A class is called a *set* if it is an element of some other class. The axioms of NBG imply the existence of the universal class $\mathbf V$ containing all sets as elements. Axioms of NBG allow to make the following six basic operations over classes $X$, $Y$:

- **The difference:** $X\setminus Y=\{z:z\in X\wedge z\notin Y\}$;
- **The Cartesian product:** $X\times Y=\{\langle x,y\rangle:x\in X\wedge y\in Y\}$;
- **The transposition:** $X^{-1}=\{\langle y,x\rangle:\langle x,y\rangle\in X\}$;
- **The cyclic permutation:** $X^\circlearrowright=\{\langle\langle z,x\rangle,y\rangle:\langle\langle x,y\rangle,z\rangle\in X\}$;
- **The domain:** $\DeclareMathOperator\dom{dom}\dom[X]=\{x:\exists y\;\langle x,y\rangle\in X\}$.
- **The membership:** $X_\in=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X:x\in y\}$.

A class $X$ is called *constructible* if it can be constructed from the universal class $\mathbf V$ applying finitely many basic operations over classes. For example, the empty set is constructible because $\emptyset=\mathbf V\setminus\mathbf V$. [Gödel's Class Existence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)  implies that a class is constructible if it can be described by a formula with a unique parameter $\mathbf V$ and all quantifiers running over elements of $\mathbf V$.  It is clear that there are only countably many constructible classes.

All possible compositions of basic operations can be effectively enumerated by the set $T=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}7^{2^{<n}}$ of 7-labeled full binary trees of finite height.

The idea of this enumeration is as follows. First, enumerate the basic operations over classes $X$, $Y$:

\begin{align*}
& G_0(X,Y):=X, \\
& G_1(X,Y):=X\setminus Y, \\
& G_2(X,Y)=X\times Y, \\
& G_3(X,Y):=X^{-1}, \\
& G_4(X,Y)=X^\circlearrowright \\
& G_5(X,Y):=\dom[X], \\
& G_6(X,Y)=X_\in.
\end{align*}

Let $2^{<\omega}=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}2^n$ be the full binary tree and for every $n\in\omega$, let $2^{<n}=\bigcup_{k\in n}2^k$ be the full binary tree of height $n$.
For every $k\in\{0,1\}$, consider the function $\vec k:2^{<\omega}\to 2^{<\omega}$, $\vec k:f\mapsto \{\langle 0,k\rangle:\langle i+1,v\rangle:\langle i,v\rangle\in f\}$ and observe that $\vec k[2^n]\subseteq 2^{n+1}$.

For every $n\in\omega$, function $\lambda:2^{<n}\to 7=\{0,1,2,\dotsc,6\}$, and class $X$, consider the class $G_\lambda(X)$ defined by the recursive formula $G_\lambda(X)=X$ if $n=0$ and  $G_\lambda(X)=G_{\lambda(0)}(G_{\lambda\circ \vec 0}(X),G_{\lambda\circ \vec 1}(X))$ if $n>0$. So, $G_\lambda$ represents a composition of the basic operations taken in the order suggested by the labels at the vertices of the binary tree $2^{<n}$.

A class $X$ is constructible if and only if $X=G_\lambda(\mathbf V)$ for some $n\in\omega^\star$ and $\lambda\in 7^{2^{<n}}$. Here $\omega^\star$ is the set of "standard" numbers in the model of NBG. So, the constructibility of classes is an external notion to the model of NBG. Here we assume that NBG is not contradictory and fix some model of NBG. This model contains an element $\omega$ whose elements are natural numbers in the model. Among those natural numbers, there are standard natural numbers, which are successors of the empty set (from the viewpoint of the universe in which the model of NBG lives).

Let $T=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}7^{2^{<n}}$ be the set of all 7-labeled binary trees of finite height. This set is a countable constructible subset of the model.

**Claim.** There exists a constructible class $C\subseteq T\times\mathbf V$ such that for every standard number $n\in\omega^\star$ and every 7-labeled tree $\lambda\in 7^{2^{<n}}$, the class $C_\lambda=\{x\in \mathbf V:\langle\lambda,x\rangle\in C\}$ coincides with the class $G_\lambda(\mathbf V)$.

Assume for a moment that the Claim is proved. The constructibility of the class $C$ implies the constructibility of the class $\Lambda=\{\lambda\in T:\langle\lambda,\lambda\rangle\notin C\}$.
Then there exists a standard number $n\in\omega^\star\subseteq\omega$ and a 7-labeled tree $\lambda\in 7^{2^{<n}}$ such that $\Lambda=C_\lambda:=\{x\in\mathbf V:\langle\lambda,x\rangle\in C\}$. Now we have a paradox of Russell's type:

- if $\lambda\in\Lambda$, then $\lambda\in C_\lambda$ and hence $\langle\lambda,\lambda\rangle\in C$ and $\lambda\notin\Lambda$;
- if $\lambda\notin\Lambda$, then  $\langle\lambda,\lambda\rangle\in C$ and hence $\lambda\in C_\lambda=\Lambda$.

In both cases, we obtain a contradiction.

*Proof of Claim.* Let $\mathbf{On}$ be the class of ordinals and $(V_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbf{On}}$ be the von Neumann hierarchy, which can be identified with the class $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathbf{On}}\{\alpha\}\times V_\alpha$. It can be shown that both these classes are constructible (because they can be defined by formulas in which quantifiers run over elements of the universal class $\mathbf V$). It can be shown that for every standard number $n\in\omega^\star\subseteq\omega$, every 7-labeled tree $\lambda\in 7^{2^{<n}}$ and every ordinal $\alpha$ there exists an ordinal $\beta$ such that $V_\alpha\cap G_\lambda(\mathbf V)=V_\alpha\cap G_\lambda(V_\gamma)$ for all ordinals $\gamma\ge\beta$.

Applying the Theorem of Recursion, for every ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ one can construct a class $C_{\alpha,\beta}\subseteq T\times\mathbf V$ such that for every standard number $n\in\omega^\star\subseteq\omega$ and 7-labeled tree $\lambda\in 7^{2^{<n}}$ we have $\{x\in \mathbf V:\langle \lambda,x\rangle\in C_{\alpha,\beta}\}=V_\alpha\cap C_\lambda(V_\beta)\}$. Moreover, the recursive definition of the indexed sequence $(C_{\alpha,\beta})_{\alpha,\beta\in\mathbf{On}}$ shows that it is constructible as a subclass of $\mathbf{On}\times\mathbf{On}\times T\times\mathbf V$ (because it is defined by a formula whose quantifiers run over elements of the universal set). For every ordinal $\alpha$ consider the class $$C_\alpha=\{\langle\lambda,x\rangle\in T\times\mathbf V:\exists \beta\in\mathbf{On}\;\forall \gamma\in \mathbf{On}\; (\beta\le \gamma\to \langle \lambda,x\rangle \in C_{\alpha,\gamma})\}.$$ The constructibility of the family $(C_{\alpha,\beta})_{\alpha,\beta\in \mathbf{On}}$ implies the constructibility of the set indexed family $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbf {On}}$ (identified with the subclass $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathbf{On}}\{\alpha\}\times C_\alpha$ of the class $\mathbf{On}\times (T\times\mathbf V)$. The constructibility of the indexed family $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbf{On}}$ implies the constructibility of the class
$$C=\{\langle \lambda,x\rangle\in T\times\mathbf V:\exists \alpha\in\mathbf{On}\;\langle\lambda,x\rangle\in C_\alpha\},$$ which has the property, required in the Claim. $\square$

So

> **Question.** In which place does this argument proving the inconsistency of NBG contain a gap?

Comment: Since your definition of constructible classes does not allow arbitrary sets as parameters, you *cannot* construct a constructible class $C_{α,β}⊆T×V$ such that ... for every ordinals $\alpha,\beta$. This would require the use of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as parameters.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I constuct those classes $(C_{\alpha,\beta})_{\alpha,\beta\in \mathbf{On}}$ as one constructible subclass of $\mathbf{On}\times\mathbf{\mathbf On}\times T\times\mathbf V$ and the latter class does not have any parameter besides $\mathbf V$. And the same with the indexed family $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbf{On}}$: it is just a constructible subclass of $\mathbf{\mathbf On}\times T\times\mathbf V$. Now I will correct that place in my argument. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: Actually, even before that: recursion only allows you to construct  a sequence of *sets*. You cannot construct a sequence of *proper classes* by recursion; NBG cannot prove that even for recursion over $\omega$, let alone larger ordinals. Which also testifies to the fact that, even in stronger set theories where the sequence provably exists, it is *not* definable by a formula without class quantifiers, thus there is no reason for it to be constructible in your sense.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek No, the Theorem of Recursion does extend to any well-founded classes. More precisely, for any class $X$, well-founded set-like relation $R$ and any  function $F:X\times \mathbf V\to\mathbf V$ there exists a unique  function $G:X\to\mathbf V$ such that $G(x)=F(x,G{\restriction}_{R^-(x)}$ for every $x\in X$, where $R^-(x)=\{z\in\mathbf V:\langle z,x\rangle\in R\}\setminus\{x\}$. The proof of this version of the Recursion Theorem is standard: the function $G$ is the union of the class of partial functions that satisfy the recursive definition of $G$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek In this general version of Recursion Theorem, $F,R,G$ are classes, not necessarily sets. So, a recursion over the class of ordinals is legal in NBG and is expressed by a formula with quantifiers running over sets, so the function $G$ is constructible whenever $F$ and $R$ are constructible. For the proof of this general version of Recursion Theorem, see Theorem 22.1 in this book: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01613.pdf

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Concerning constructing a sequence of proper classes by recursion, you are right: I cannot construct such a sequence using the Recursion Theorem. That is why I first construct the indexed sequence of sets $(C_{\alpha,\beta})_{\alpha,\beta\in\mathbf{On}}$, which allow me to define a "legal" indexed family $C=(C_\lambda)_{\lambda\in T}$ of proper classes such that $C_\lambda=G_\lambda(\mathbf V)$ for a "standard" $\lambda$, and thus obtain a contradiction of NBG.

Comment: I do not know why you write "**No**, the Theorem of Recursion does extend ..." when your comment perfectly agrees with what I wrote. This is the usual recursion theorem for defining sequences of *sets*. But when you write "consider the class $G_λ(X)$ defined by the recursive formula ...",  you are attempting to define a sequence of *proper classes* by recursion over $2^{<\omega}$. You cannot do that in NBG.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek This "No" concerned my first impression that your comment concerned impossibility of recursion over proper classes (in indexes) and after writing my comment I realized that you had in mind recursion over counatble sets but with purpose of constructing proper classes. When I wrote $G_\lambda(X)$ is defined by the recursive formula, I have in mind that $\lambda$ is "standard" 7-labeled tree and recursion is understood from the ambient universe where the model lives.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek  When we make recursive construction of sets $V_\alpha\cap G_\lambda(V_\beta)$ both meaning (internal and external) produce the same elements of the model for "standard" $\lambda$'s. Taking limits of those sets $V_\alpha\cap G_\lambda(V_\beta)$ produce a desirable indexed class $(C_\lambda)_{\lambda\in T}$ consisting of proper classes such that $C_\lambda=G_\lambda(V)$ for "standard" $\lambda$.

Comment: "there exists an ordinal $β$ such that $V_α∩G_λ(V)=V_α∩G_λ(V_γ)$ for all ordinals $γ≥β$" is not true in general. For example, take $\lambda$ such that $G_\lambda(X)=\{x\in X:\forall y\in X\,\exists z\in X\,y\in z\}$ (which is either $\emptyset$ or $X$) for all $X$. Then $G_\lambda(V)=V$, but $G_\lambda(V_\gamma)=\emptyset$ whenever $\gamma$ is a successor ordinal. It is only true that for each $\alpha$ and $\lambda$, there are arbitrarily large $\gamma$ such that $V_\alpha\cap G_\lambda(V)=V_\alpha\cap G_\lambda(V_\gamma)$.

Comment: The principle of recursion over classes is known as ETR (elementary transfinite recursion) and it is not provable in GBC. For example, the first-order truth predicate is defined by such a recursion of length $\omega$, and there are models of GBC in which every class is first-order definable, but by Tarski's theorem truth is never itself definable. For some further analysis of ETR, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03700.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you very much for your comment, which resolves my question and also explains why we cannot replace this particular external recursive definition of a sequence of proper classes by the internal one. So, the NBG is saved! Very good :)

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it took me several iterations to read and understand the question properly.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Is there any standard name for classes which are constructible by finitely many basic operations from the universal class?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek This question was important for me because I started to rewrite the chapter on Godel's constructible universe in my book (from arxiv) and encountered this problem, which stopped the process. Now I can proceed further. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @TarasBanakh "NBG is saved!" To be honest, I don't think it was ever in any danger... :-)

Comment: @TimothyChow This was a joke, of course! When I was a student I was said about Godel's Theorem on the impossibility of proving the consistency of Mathematics, so at each moment someone can find a contradiction, after which all math will immediately lose its value. On the other hand, the (Naive) Set Theory indeed was is a danger because of Russell's Paradox.

Comment: @TarasBanakh You may enjoy the short story "Division By Zero" by Ted Chiang (reprinted in the anthology *Stories of Your Life and Others*).

Comment: @TimothyChow Indeed, good story, very appropriate to my today's situation. Thank you for the suggestion. Now my daughter has found me the file in Internet and I will read it.

Comment: @TarasBanakh To answer your queston, the issue for me would be the sense of "finite", whether you mean finite in the meta theory or the internal notion of finite, which might after all be nonstandard. If you use the metatheoretic notion of finite, then you will get definable classes. But if you intend some internal process of iterating, then you will get nonstandard versions of being definable (when indeed the classes exist), and they won't necessarily agree with being externally definable.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Dear Joel David, thank you for the comment. Now (with help of Emil Jerabek ) I have understood in which place I made a gap. Nonetheless, I would like to use the notion of a class that can be defined as $\{x:\varphi(x,\mathbf V)\}$ where $\varphi(x,v)$ is a formula with two free variables $x,v$ and all quantifiers running over sets. Do you know of any commonly accepted name for such definable classes. There are only countably many of them (in the sense of metatheory), but they include quite important classes like the class $\mathbf{On}$ of all ordinals or the ordinal $\omega$.

Comment: I would call those the first-order definable classes without parameters. The property of being such a class, however, is not expressible, even in the second-order language of GBC, and for this reason, the notion can be deemed purely meta-theoretic rather than a legitmate concept that is part of the object theory.

Comment: Meanwhile, it is a theorem of mine with David Linetsky and Jonas Reitz that every countable model of GBC has an extension in which every class is definable like that without parameters. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thank you for the links to your papers. Thinking on definability (or constructibility) of classes, I came to the conclusion that it is expressible in the language of Class Theory: a class $X$ is definable if $\exists n\in\omega \;\exists \lambda\in 8^{2^{<n}} \exists Y (Y\subseteq 2^{\le n}\times\mathbf V\wedge Y_\emptyset=X\wedge (\forall t\in 2^n X_t=\mathbf V)\wedge (\forall t\in 2^{<n} X_t=G_{\lambda(t)}(X_{t{\hat\;}0},X_{t{\hat\;}1}))$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins In the above formula $Y_t=\{y\in\mathbf V:\langle t,y\rangle\in Y\}$ for any set $t$ and class $Y$. So, definability can be expressed in the language of Class Theory. The only problem that the existence of a single class (representing all definable classes) cannot be proved because of the absence of the recursion Theorem for constructing sequence of proper classes.

Comment: No, that doesn't define definability, since the model might have nonstandard $n$. This is the internal notion of definability, and a nonstandard model can think something is definable in your sense, without it actually being definable. For example, take a pointwise definable model of NGB, where every class is definable without parameters, and then take an elementary extension of it. The new extension objects cannot be actually definable, but by elementary they will think that every class is definable in your sense.

Comment: An $\omega$-nonstandard model of NGB can never have a expressible account of actual definibility, since then it could define the standard cut in $\omega$ as consisting of those $n$ for which there is something definable by a term of size $n$. But one cannot define the standard cut in $\omega$, since there is no least nonstandard element.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Nonetheless that internal formula agrees with the "standard" definability in the sense that definable classes in the standard sense are definable in the internal sense, but not vice versa. This is at least something (I mean better than nothing).

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins In relation to your latest comment: An $\omega$-nonstandard *spartan* model of NBG, i.e., a model of NBG in which the collection of classes coincides with the collection of the parametrically definable subsets of the ambient model of ZF, the standard cut is indeed definable, see (*) on page 22 of the following (preprint of) a joint paper of ours: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02729.pdf (as pointed out in the paper, the basic idea goes back to a 1950 paper of Mostowski).  Indeed in such models the satisfaction predicate for the ambient model of ZF is definable.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The internal definability of classes can be helpful because it allows introducing a well-defined axiom, which is stronger than $V=L$: every class is L-definable, i.e., can be constructed (jn this internal sense) from L and elements of L. Under this axiom not only does the class of sets $L$ admit a well-order but also the "family" of all classes can be well-ordered in a suitable sense (by some well-defined formula of the class theory). Do you know if anybody has thought about such a strong Class Constructibility Axiom?

Comment: @TarasBanakh Yes, that principle arises in the mutual interpretability result between KM and ZFC-+the largest cardinal is inaccessible. An intermediate step attains the class collection axiom CC by going to those classes that are (internally) relatively constructible.

Comment: @AliEnayat My point was that if (contrary to fact) the notion of "definable" was itself expressible in an $\omega$-nonstandard model, then one could define the standard cut, and this doesn't require the spartan assumption. A number $n$ is standard iff there is a definable class X and an (internal) $\Sigma_n$ truth predicate T showing that X is definable at that level, but it is not definable at any earlier level.

Comment: But I understand your point now---it is not a contradiction to define the standard cut, if the definition is second order.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Hi Joel, I was confused by your statement "An ω-nonstandard model of NGB can never have a expressible account of actual definibility", since in spartan models (whether ω-nonstandard or ω-standard) the truth predicate for the ambient model of ZF is definable.  Perhaps by "definability" you meant definability in the model of NBG, not definability in the ZF-model of the model of NBG?

Comment: My comment was wrong, since as you mention we can have a second-order definition of the standard cut. (And yes, I was referring to first-order definability of the classes.) I was emphasizing the distinction between the internal representation of definability (as Taras is doing) and the external model-theoretic notion of definability. In the parameter-free case, these are not the same.

Comment: Meanwhile, my comments about the non-expressivity of definability in $\omega$-nonstandard models works in Kelley-Morse, where the standard cut cannot be definable even in the second-order language, and this shows that there is no definition of (meta-theoretic) definability that works in all NGB models. (But also, the nontrivial elementary extensions of pointwise definable model of NGB also shows this.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for the clarification Joel, as I suspected you had Kelley-Morse in mind.

Comment: Due to several inappropriate "answers," I've gone ahead and protected this question; feel free to un-protect if that was an inappropriate move here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The comments to the question, especially those by Emil Jeřábek and Joel Hamkins make it clear that the proposed inconsistency proof breaks down because the recursive construction carried out in the proposed proof of inconsistency cannot be implemented in NBG.

As pointed out first by Mostowski in his 1950 paper [Some impredicative definitions in set theory](https://eudml.org/doc/213208), when it comes to recursive constructions, the problem with NBG (as opposed to the much stronger system KM of Kelley and Morse) is that, the scheme of induction over the natural numbers is not provable in NBG. I would like to outline Mostowski's reasoning here since it sheds light on why the recursion proposed by Taras Banakh need not succeed in an arbitrary model of NBG.

The main idea is that within NBG we can describe, via a second order definition (i.e., by quantifying over classes of NBG) a subset $I$ of the ambient natural numbers of the NBG model such that NBG can prove that $I$ is closed under predecessors, contains $0$, and is closed under successors, but NBG cannot prove that $I$ coincides with the set $\omega$ of natural numbers (in the sense of NBG).

The basic idea is devilishly simple: let $I$ consist of numbers $k$ such that there is a class $S$ (in the ambient model of NBG) such that $S$ is a $k$-satisfaction class, i.e., $S$  satisfies Tarski's compositional clauses for a satisfaction predicate for the structure $(\mathbf{V},\in)$ (in the sense of the ambient NBG model) for *formulae of depth at least* $k$; here the depth of a formula $\varphi$ is the length of the longest path in the "parsing tree" of $\varphi$ (also known as the "formation tree" or "syntactic tree" of $\varphi$).

With $I$ defined as above, we can specify a unary formula $\sigma(x)$ in the language of NBG such that, provably in NBG, $\sigma(x)$ satisfies Tarski's compositional clauses for all set-theoretical formula whose depth (as defined above) lies in $I$. *In particular, $\sigma(x)$ correctly decides the truth of all set-theoretical sentences in the ambient ZF model of NBG since for each standard natural number $k$, NBG can prove that $k \in I$.*

$\sigma(x)$ expresses: $x$ is a set-theoretical formula (with parameters) $\varphi(m_1,...,m_s)$,  $\mathrm{depth}(\varphi) \in I$, and there is a class $S$ (in the sense of NBG) such that $\varphi(m_1,...,m_s) \in S$ and $S$ is a $k$-satisfaction predicate for $k=\mathrm{depth}(\varphi)$. Note that, provably in NBG, any two $k$-satisfaction classes agree on the truth-evaluation of formulae of depth at most $k$.

> Mostowski's construction unveiled a rather intriguing
> phenomena: there can be a theory $T^+$ [in this case NBG] which possesses a truth-predicate for
> a theory $T$ [in this case ZF], and yet the formal consistency of $T$ is unprovable in
> $T^+$ (due to the lack of sufficient formal induction in $U$ [because Con(ZF) is not provable in GB, since GB is set-theoretically conservative over ZF, and of course ZF cannot prove Con(ZF)].

With the above definition of $\sigma$ at our disposal, we can write a formula $\theta$ in the language of NBG that asserts that every class is definable in the sense of $\sigma$ in the following sense:

**Theorem.** *If $(\mathcal{M},\frak{X})$ is a model of NBG, where $\mathcal{M}=(M,E)$ is a model of ZF, and $\frak{X}$ is a subset of the powerset of $M$ that specifies the classes of the model, and $M$ is $\omega$-standard, then $(\mathcal{M},\frak{X}) \models \theta$ iff $(\mathcal{M},\frak{X})$ is spartan, i.e., $\frak{X}$ consists of subsets of $M$ that are parametrically definable in $\mathcal{M}$.*

**N.B.** In the above, the $\omega$-standardness hypothesis is only used in the left-to-right direction, in other words, *$\theta$ holds in every spartan model of* NBG.

Besides the Mostowski paper referenced above, readers interested in the history  of this subject might want to also examine John Myhill's 1952 paper [The hypothesis that all classes are nameable.](https://www.pnas.org/doi/epdf/10.1073/pnas.38.11.979)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What about the existence of definable subsets of finite sets (see my question https://mathoverflow.net/q/444551/61536). Can this fact be proved in NBG or also similar problems arise?

Comment: @TarasBanakh Thanks for the correction. I will think about your other MO question and will report back if I have any success.